Generic DataPipeline Framework Using Scala3
I have the following design for writing a generic data pipeline using GenericReader[+Out] and GenericWriter[-In] And a Transformer[From, To] which will convert Out => In. These readers and writers are defined as the part of IOClient and I have multiple IOClients example Mongo, FTP, S3 etc. I want to use these generic traits in a method called process this method should be generic enough so that I keep on adding IOClients and I don't have to change the processing of it.
I have the below design currently, Please suggest Improvements if there are any.
trait IOClient:
  type Out 
  type In  

  def reader: GenericReader[Out]
  def writer: GenericWriter[In]


trait Transformer[From, To]:
  def transform(from: From) : To

trait GenericReader[+Out]:
  def read() : Future[Out]

trait GenericWriter[-In]:
  def write(data: In): Future[Boolean]


As there are multiple Implementation of IOClient ReadType Out and Write type In can be anything Want it to work for any Combination of Out and In
process method should look something like this.
def process(
    readClient: IOClient,
    writeClient: IOClient
)(using
    transformer: Transformer[readClient.Out, writeClient.In],
    ec: ExecutionContext
): Future[Boolean] = {
  for
    readData <- readClient.reader.read()
    transformedData = transformer.transform(readData)
    result <- writeClient.writer.write(transformedData)
  yield result
}

The problem I am facing is I am getting compile time error saying no Implicit found for Transfomrer[ReadClient.Out, WriteCliet.In]
I have written few transformers but they are not liked to Out and In hence I am getting the compile time error. What should be the correct approach to tackle this, should I redesign the whole thing or is there any better way to implement this?
Please provide your inputs.
Example transformers:
  given identityTransformer[From]: Transformer[From, From] with
    def transform(from: From): From = from
  

  given docToStr : Transformer[Document, String] with
    override def transform(from: Document): String = from.toJson
  
  given strToInt: Transformer[String, Int] with
    override def transform(from: String): String = from.toIntOption.getOrElse(0)
...


Thanks In Advance!!

It would help if you can share a full snippet that actually fails, like the implementation of the transformers can be empty / dummy, but we need their type signature and a full code that can be copied and pasted and results in an error; you may use Scastie for that. - The code as it is, should work AFAIK, personally I would not add the IOClient trait, I don't see it adding any value.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your comment, So actually transformer are more like a map operation in this case example String to Int then or String to Json or Json to String etc. etc. let me add few examples in the question itSelf.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez actually IOClient is being resolved with some preprocessing of data hence I kept it, Without having IOClient it would be really difficult to resolve these client that's why I think this layer of abstraction is needed but please correct me if I am wrong.

IMHO, you'd need sth like Aux pattern in this function to make it work. Otherwise inference won't relate path dependent types to their actual types (and implicits).

@RamanMishra again, please provide code that actually fails, this works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/e8cgtSHhRBun7x4NNVM7NA/4 as expected. - About IOClient I don't understand anything you said, no why it is important, but whatever. With the code provided it just feels redundant.

BTW, personal advice, I would not make the transformers implicit. I would just pass them manually.

Please provide MCVE

@DmytroMitin I have updated the code which is giving me the compilation error, sorry for the late response. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BqCU9XVaT0WeBbHoVZBzCg

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez here is the updated code IOClient are being resolved using some environment variable and the type of these client depend on these env variable here is the updated code which give me error. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BqCU9XVaT0WeBbHoVZBzCg

@RamanMishra the problem is that as Dmytro pointed out you erased the types and thus the compiler can't simply resolve the information anymore. You want a compile time operation like resolving implicits to be determined by a runtime value. That is simply impossible, is like wanting to eat before cooking the food.

@DmytroMitin I still have the same issue, because the src and destination are being resolved at runtime here is an example https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QhaycidORqGRBIN3oSqzLQ (let me know even if it's possible to do this) may be using macros or something like compile time reflection.

@RamanMishra what about if you organize the code like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/sHbPOC25RL27s2tVHnzvZQ/6 ?

Type inference works for type parameters (generics) differently than for type members. While type parameters should be inferred (or minimized if they can't), type members can remain abstract.
Scala: Abstract types vs generics (answer)
What's different between "def apply[T](c:T)" and "type T;def apply(c:T)"
For convenience let's define Aux-type:
object IOClient:
  type Aux[I, O] = IOClient { type In = I; type Out = O }

When you define
case class ResolvedSourceDest(srcClient: IOClient, destClient: IOClient)

here IOClient is similar to existential IOClient.Aux[?, ?] (or IOClient.Aux[I, O] with not inferred I, O):
summon[IOClient =:= IOClient.Aux[?, ?]] // compiles
summon[IOClient.Aux[?, ?] =:= IOClient] // compiles

Although TestClient is-a IOClient.Aux[String, Int], in ResolvedSourceDest(TestClient, TestClient) types In, Out remain abstract.
Try to make class ResolvedSourceDest generic:
case class ResolvedSourceDest[In, Out](srcClient: IOClient.Aux[In, Out], destClient: IOClient.Aux[In, Out])

Then your code compiles:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3f7WDNvuTUmnZIqkBBuagw/1
If you made In, Out type parameters rather than type members, this would be more obvious:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3f7WDNvuTUmnZIqkBBuagw/2
One more option to make ResolvedSourceDest generic is
case class ResolvedSourceDest[C <: IOClient](srcClient: C, destClient: C)

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3f7WDNvuTUmnZIqkBBuagw/3
